# Regex issue - unknown whitespace

Tags: javascript, parsing

Basically my problem is my program takes text input that is full of random spaces, tabs and other whitespace units (line breaks as well, but not as many).

I have successfully removed all tabs...

```
// Parse the input box into an array
var inputArr = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.split(/[\t]/);
```

Now the text looks something like this...

"Dummy Field for Hiding Groups , , , , , , ,*Role ,Go To , , , Collapse section Summary , , , ,Name ,Doe,John ,Details ,Customer ,John Doe Inc.

My problem:  I have a switch...

```
switch(inputArr[i]) {
```

...that has several cases...

```
        case ("Name" || "Name " || " Name" || " Name "):
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == ("Summary" || "Summary " || " Summary" || " Summary ")) {
                contNameBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case ("Details" || "Details " || " Details" || " Details "):
            if(contNameBool == true) {
                contNameBool = false;
                break;
            } else if(contNameBool == false && compNameBool == true) {
                compNameBool = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case ("Customer" || "Customer " || " Customer" || " Customer "):
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == "Details") {
                contNameBool = false;
                compNameBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Address":
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == "Profile") {
                compNameBool = false;
                emailBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case ("VISA" || "MASTERCARD" || "AMERICAN" || "DISCOVER"):
            emailBool = false;
            break;
        case "Show":
            if(inputArr[i + 1] == "next" && inputArr[1 + 2] == "row") {
                accountLinesArray.length = inputArr[i - 1];
                for(j = 0; j < accountLinesArray.length; j++) {
                    accountLinesArray[j] = new account();
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Order":
            if(inputArr[i + 1] == "ID" && inputArr[i + 2] == "MRC") {
                accountsBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
```

As you can probably tell, I am trying to get my program to identify certain key words in the text and toggle some booleans accordingly. The switch statement doesn't seem to ever go into any of the cases, no matter how I configure the conditions. For example the case...

```
case ("Name" && "Name " && " Name" && " Name "):
```

Doesn't trigger, even if I use ||.

Before anyone posts it. I realize my code is sloppy at best. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're splitting on tabs only.  To split on any sequence of whitespace chars, do this:

```
var inputArr = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.split(/\s+/);
```

This will reduce the number of cases you need to handle, so you won't need to check for "Name", "Name ", " Name", or " Name ", just "Name":

```
case "Name":
    ...
    break;
```

Second, this doesn't do as you're expecting (see explanation below):

```
inputArr[i - 1] == ("Summary" || "Summary " || " Summary" || " Summary ")
```

but with the first change above, you can just compare against "Summary" anyway.

Third, for the cases where you do want to match against completely different values, you can do this:

```
case "VISA":
case "MASTERCARD":
case "AMERICAN":
case "DISCOVER":
    emailBool = false;
    break;
```

Finally, you really should rethink your whole approach, but without more specifics, it's hard to give you any meaningful advice about that...

Good luck!

EDIT (Why `inputArr[i - 1] == ("Summary" || "Summary " || ...` doesn't work):

In Javascript, non-null strings count as true and `||` and `&&` can be used as short-circuit evaluations. For example, `("Name" || " Name")` get's evaluated as `"Name"` because `"Name"` is true so the rest of the equation doesn't need to be evaluated. Likewise, `("Name" && " Name")` would be equivalent to `" Name"`, because `"Name"` is true so it moves on to the next one, `" Name"` which is also true and is the end of the statement. To do what you were attempting would need to be done something like:

```
(inputArr[i - 1] == "Summary") || (inputArr[i - 1] == "Summary ") || ...
```

or could be done more simply by using a regex:

```
!!inputArr[i - 1].match("Summary").length
// Be careful though, as this could also match something like "NotASummaryDude"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually needed to split on tabs and not on all whitespace, I accidentally put in the word, "spaces" when I meant, "tabs". If I remove all tabs I don't know how my program would be able to identify a blank field later on.

Answer (score 0):

After applying Ray's suggestions, you might also want to remove the empty elements from the array:

```
for (var i=inputArr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    if (inputArr[i] == '' || !inputArr[i].match(/[^\s]/)) inputArr.splice(i,1)
}
```

Comment: I attempted to implement this, but it gives me an error when the code follows inputArr[i] = inputArr[i].split(/\s+/); Any ideas why?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the code but inputArr[i].split(/\s+/) will split the array element 'i' so inputArr[i] will itself become an array. Perhaps the code is attempting to apply the regex to an array rather than a string?